# Errors when compiling Dolphin emulator (libx)

Tags: release-freya, software-installation

I am trying to compile the Dolphin emulator by following [this guide](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Building_Dolphin_on_Linux#Other_Linux_Distributions)

But during the make install step, I get these errors:

```
make[2]: ** [Source/Core/InputCommon/CMakeFiles/inputcommon.dir/Src/ControllerEmu.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Source/Core/InputCommon/CMakeFiles/inputcommon.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems to be problems with Libx and I have tried to reinstall the libx11-dev and libx11-6 packages, but that didn't do anything.

Comment: please add output of `cmake ..`

Comment: I think the output is not really right. I tried adding the command from [link](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=21573.0) and it seemed to change the output of cmake ... I don't know how to change it back. But here is the current output: [link](http://pastebin.com/dEeK3h76)